# A Chemdrawing software?

Tags: software

I would like to know about a Chemdrawing sotware for 2-d molecular structures. it should be mainly linux based (but if it supports other OS's then that would be great)

Comment: There are tons of platform-independant HTML+JS ones like http://www.emolecules.com/ . Also: This question has no _correct_ answer, per se, and should be CW. Also2: This is easily googleable. Also3: Maybe this should be asked on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229) instead?

Comment: Community: please chime in here on your opinion on on-topicness of such questions: http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/73/are-software-questions-on-topic

Comment: Questions asking for a list of items with no critera for evaluating the answers are very problematic. There are many answers that are equally valid, resulting in voting purely based on popularity. Their value also tends to decay a lot when they're not curated carefully.

Comment: You have an up-to-date list [here](http://www.redbrick.dcu.ie/~noel/linux4chemistry/); just select your criteria and choose “2D Draw” as the category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd really reccomend the free **[Marvin suite](http://www.chemaxon.com/products/marvin/marvinsketch/)** from ChemAxon.

MarvinSketch (the actual drawing package) hasn't disappointed me in the past and has a wide feature set.  In addition to just being able to draw compounds in Lewis format, the software includes plugins to name what you have drawn (systematic/traditional), predict properties, change atom and bond properties, generate stereoisomers and much more that I haven't got the experience to do anything more than experiment with!

You can view what you have drawn in Lewis form and also as a 3D structure should you wish to.  It supports many chemical drawing filetypes.

[Here](http://www.chemaxon.com/products/marvin/marvinsketch/) is the product page, including brochure and technical details.  It is Java based so works on Mac, Windows, Linux and is even available [on the web](http://www.webqc.org/moleculareditor2.php) (but is quite slow to generate properties etc. - I'd reccomend doing this locally).

Comment: thanks that is a great soft though i have to switch between sketcher and viewer

Comment: You can switch quickly between the two (and save as image etc.) using CTRL-SHIFT-V in sketch :)

Answer (score 2):

Go to this [link](http://en.bio-soft.net/chemdraw.html), it has links to many chemical drawing softwares
 but I will recommend [Chemdraw](http://www.cambridgesoft.com/software/ChemDraw/) and [Chemsketch](http://www.acdlabs.com/resources/freeware/). Chemdraw is a commercial version but chemsketch is a freeware and it works on both windows and  linux operating system. I am currently using Chemsketch and it is very good.