# What software do professional chemists use?

Tags: software

What software is used to create skeletal formula diagrams, create 3D models and whatnot? For example, on Wikipedia pages for molecules, you see standard 3D models and skeletal models which I assume are made with certain chemistry programs rather than some widespread ones.

Also, what programs are used to write chemistry papers? I know languages like LaTeX are used for mathematics and I can see you could definitely write a chemistry paper using such a program; I am curious to what actual chemists use.

Comment: [molden](http://www.cmbi.ru.nl/molden/), jackal (old, good for b/w crystal structures and such), [hyperchem](http://www.hyper.com/), [avogadro](https://avogadro.cc/), [crystalmaker](http://www.crystalmaker.com/), their own stuff

Comment: There are several software solutions for each problem you mentioned as well as to other ones.  If you are doing Chemical research at a university/in a lab, many of this software are available through campus licenses, so check those first.

Comment: @JoshuaFarrell please let us know a) what operating system you are using; b) are you affiliated with a university or any other institution that may have licences available. The things are (sadly), many software pieces chemists need cost ridiculous amount of money. Please leave a note, if you prefer [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software).

Comment: @Joshua Farell Regarding the "skeletal representation" in wikipedia you refer to, this in part is partially due to a listing of software (at least, in principle) available: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecule_editor . More importantly, however, regarding *consistency* of the representations, similar to publishers where you submit an article to a journal, wikipedia has a dedicated set of guidelines how to draw molecules, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Chemistry/Structure_drawing

Comment: Chemdraw/Marvin Sketch (Draw structures), Kaleidagraph (Easy graphing program, I like it far more than excel), VESTA (Visualize X-Ray Diffraction data/ others), Gaussian/VASP/QE/Calypso (Computational chemistry packages, some are useful for NMR predictions, among other things), Python (Makes more complicated data manipulation a breeze). Everyone will have a different toolkit. I generally use Word to write papers, as Chemdraw has word plugins that are nice.

Comment: @andselisk I am using a Macintosh so OSX and next year I will be affiliated with a university but for mathematics

Comment: @JoshuaFarrell Oh. For macOS you might want to have a look at http://www.macinchem.org/, I guess, unless you need something really specific. Genarally, [MarvinSketch](https://www.chemaxon.com/products/marvin/marvinsketch/) for 2D structures and [Avogadro](https://avogadro.cc/) for 3D structures are a good start. Regarding LaTeX, I use it whenever possible, if you really want, you can check out my [preamble](https://github.com/andselisk/chex/blob/master/preamble.tex) to get an idea what packages might come in handy.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/54548/software-for-visualization-of-3d-models-of-chemical-structures-with-atomic-orbit?rq=1 https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/246/a-chemdrawing-software?rq=1